# Learning to create Windows MCE plugins

Tags: c#, windows-media-center, windows-mce

I am currently mostly a Java Developer, and would like to know if one would be able to creating Windows MCE plugins for popular services using a language like C#?  Where would i find resources to learn how to write MCE plugins using C# if at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

Really to find these resources you are going to have to be a bit more specific as to what resources you actually need.

Start with the SDK as David M suggested above, also check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb189062.aspx

Its probably going to be easier if you work out what you actually want to build, what it needs to do then research that particular area or ask specific questions rather than trying to look at writing plugins as a whole. Since you come from a Java background C# shouldnt be too hard to pick up if you dont know it already.

A quick google search for 'writing windows MCE plugins' returns a few good results too.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895967.aspx) for this published by Microsoft. You could do a lot worse than start by downloading that and reading some of the technical articles available on that page.